# How do I set up a multiplayer game?

Tags: hammerfight

Hammerfight appears to support multiplayer, as it has an option for 'multy-mouse' input.  How can I actually get into a multiplayer game with a friend, and does multiplayer support mouse+gamepad input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting into a multiplayer game is actually rather easy, and there isn't much difference between a controller and a mouse (though I haven't actually tried plugging in two controllers at the same time, admittedly. Mouse + controller works like a charm).

To "enter" multiplayer mode, just click on each connected mouse or press a button on the connected controller. You should then have two (or more) cursors visible (Red and green for two players):

[image: Two cursors]

Next, pick a game mode (either arena, grim or hammerball. The story mode does not support co-op) and have each player pick a profile (in the screenshot, player 1 has already picked a profile):

[image: Choose your combatant]

Then, multiplayer madness:

[image: Multiplayer madness!]

**(!)** Notice that this can only be possible on 32-bit running Windows OS starting with Windows XP. Game doesn't support multimouse mode on 64-bit operating systems.